# Authorisation google urlfetch api only in script editor possible, not with web app/service UI

Tags: google-apps-script

We build a service with google apps script (deployed as web app).
This service script uses a google api with UrlFetchApp and oAuthConfig. Our script and service is working without problems.

Problem:
If a new user wants to use our service, he starts the service url and the service opens. In this process he has to authorise everything the script function uses without the with urlfetch used api. So, if he starts the service again, he get the error message:  "Authorization is required to perform that action".
The only way we found to authorise the urlfetch-api is that the user go into the scripteditor and start the function from the editor UI. If he do so, he can authorise this api. Afterwords he can start the service via url and everything is working well.

Do anybody know a better way to authorise the user without doing this in the editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open issue since July 2011, [issue 677](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=677) and a lot of people are waiting for that...

Answer (score 0):

User can run script directly as url from browser and will get the standard authorisation dialogue at that point. You can make it a bit more user friendly by providing a link and a tailored response in html.